Query complex data with searchkick
I'm trying to build a rather complex query with searchkick.
This is how my index is configured:
  def search_data
    {
      ticket_id: reference,
      custom_fields: _custom_fields
    }
  end

  protected

  def _custom_fields
    custom_fields.collect do |custom_field|
      "#{configuration.custom_fields.find_by(name: custom_field.name)&.id&.to_s}:#{custom_field.value}"
    end
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    {}
  end

So let's say that I have in my index an array of strings like "UUIDabc123:loremipsum".
What I would like to do is to match by id. I have tried to put the strings in a regexp (with Regexp.quote) and use it like where: {custom_fields: {in: query}} but it finds absolutely nothing, I suppose because the index is an array of strings to "partially match".
What I do is basically:
    def prepare_custom_fields(params)
      where = { custom_fields: params[:custom_fields].collect { |id| /#{Regexp.quote(id)}/ } }
      success(where:)
    end

So:
{:custom_fields=>[/6762eb2c17b94fb0d9980114/, /6762eb2c17b94fb0d9980115/, /6762eb2c17b94fb0d9980116/]}

Can someone with a better understanding of OpenSearch + Searchkick help me? Unfortunately I have many fields to query, I can't just use the body, at least that I know.

I am not 100% sure but looking at the documentation it seems like the Partial Matches section could be of use. Maybe adding searchkick word_start: [:custom_fields] and then search(params[:custom_fields].join(" "), fields: [:custom_fields], match: :word_start, operator: "or")? Another option could be search(body: {query: { match: {custom_fields: params[:custom_fields].join(" ")} }}). Open Search Docs for match
